# Transaction Signature Received But Tx never found

Tags: solana-program, python

I've been working with the Python Solana SDK to send transactions to the Solana Mainnet Beta Cluster. For endpoint connections, I've tried both QuickNode and Alchemy. Despite the SDK returning a transaction signature upon sending a transaction, I often encounter a peculiar issue where the transactions appear to never actually propagate - they cannot be found on SolScan, nor does the confirmation function in the SDK yield any results.

Interestingly, the problem seems to be mitigated somewhat when I manually specify the compute fee price and units for the transactions. After this adjustment, the frequency of the issue dropped to about 50% of the transactions. However, the problem still persists for the other half, leaving me puzzled about the root cause and the solution.

Has anyone else encountered similar issues with transactions not being found on the Solana network using the Python SDK? Are there any known workarounds or solutions to ensure consistent transaction propagation and confirmation?

Below is a simplified version of the code I use to send transactions, with the compute fee adjustments that partially solved the issue:

```
from config import SOLANA_RPC, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, TOKEN_PROGRAM_OWNER_ID, TRANSFER_COMPUTE_PRICE, TRANSFER_COMPUTE_LIMIT
from solana.rpc import types
from spl.token.client import Token
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solders.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from bot.utils.raydium.create_close_account import compute_units_limit_inx, compute_units_price_inx


class SolanaUtils:
    
    def __init__(self, web3: Client = None, token_address: str = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7", private_key: str = None,  wallet_address=None):
        self.logger = self.get_logger()
        self.keypair = Keypair.from_base58_string(private_key) if private_key else Keypair()
        
        self.name = "solana_utils"
        self.web3 = web3
        self.token_address = token_address
        self.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL = LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        
        
        self.web3 = Client(SOLANA_RPC, blockhash_cache=True, commitment='confirmed')
        self.spl = Token(conn=self.web3, pubkey=Pubkey.from_string(self.token_address), program_id=Pubkey.from_string(TOKEN_PROGRAM_OWNER_ID), payer=self.keypair)
        
        self.wallet = self.keypair.pubkey()
        
def transfer_sol(self, to: str, amount: int, priority_fee: int=0):
        print(f'Sending from the account: {self.keypair.pubkey()}')
        receiver = Pubkey.from_string(to)
        amount_in_lamports = self.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * amount - 5000 - (TRANSFER_COMPUTE_LIMIT*TRANSFER_COMPUTE_PRICE/10**6)
        transfer_ix = transfer(TransferParams(from_pubkey=self.keypair.pubkey(), to_pubkey=receiver, lamports=int(amount_in_lamports)))
        txn = Transaction()
        cp_ins = compute_units_price_inx(TRANSFER_COMPUTE_PRICE)
        cl_ins = compute_units_limit_inx(TRANSFER_COMPUTE_LIMIT)
        txn.add(transfer_ix)
        txn.add(cp_ins)
        txn.add(cl_ins)
        signers = [self.keypair]
        
        tx_sig = self.web3.send_transaction(txn, *signers)
        print("Transfer Fee TX : ",tx_sig)

        return tx_sig
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function returning a signature indicates nothing except that your transaction was successfully signed by the local keypair, which is independent of your transaction being executed and included in a block onchain. Transaction failure is a bigger subject, check out [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/how-can-i-analyze-the-reason-for-frequent-blockheightexceeded-errors/9346#9346) for more info on this.