# TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError Cant Send SPL Tokens

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I'm trying to airdrop to my users, but 9 out of 10 of the transactions I send fail, I can't understand the reason, does anyone have any suggestions?

Example Error:

```
Error sending tokens to J7R6efQq89vFoX7xK8aVEePQB9XteaoEzRwGdt2PXjhJ: TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 4hdbtQ944EuWdDt9hJK8dCzTPBPHadQh2kzDaWRTwv3oMPuBeCdocP4abNY2dLpPruqmWajF3UTbn7YytFwN4HnJ has expired: block height exceeded.
    at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy (C:\Users\mertm\Desktop\airdrop2\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6542:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.confirmTransaction (C:\Users\mertm\Desktop\airdrop2\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6370:14)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\mertm\Desktop\airdrop2\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:2158:15) {
  signature: '4hdbtQ944EuWdDt9hJK8dCzTPBPHadQh2kzDaWRTwv3oMPuBeCdocP4abNY2dLpPruqmWajF3UTbn7YytFwN4HnJ'
}
```

This is my code:

```
const { Connection, PublicKey, Keypair } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, transfer } = require('@solana/spl-token');
const fs = require('fs');
const bs58 = require('bs58');

// Adjust these variables according to your needs
const base58SeedPhrase = 'redacted';
const tokenMintAddress = 'redacted';
const recipientsPath = 'recipients.json'; // Path to your JSON file
const decimals = 9; // Token decimals

async function airdropTokens() {
  // Use the custom RPC endpoint
  const connection = new Connection('redacted', 'confirmed');

  const seedBytes = bs58.decode(base58SeedPhrase);
  const wallet = Keypair.fromSeed(seedBytes.slice(0, 32));
  const tokenMint = new PublicKey(tokenMintAddress);
  const recipients = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(recipientsPath));

  for (const { address, amount } of recipients) {
    try {
      const recipientPublicKey = new PublicKey(address);

      const senderTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        wallet,
        tokenMint,
        wallet.publicKey
      );

      const recipientTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        wallet,
        tokenMint,
        recipientPublicKey
      );

      console.log(`Sending ${amount} tokens to ${address}...`);

      await transfer(
        connection,
        wallet,
        senderTokenAccount.address,
        recipientTokenAccount.address,
        wallet.publicKey,
        amount * Math.pow(10, decimals),
        []
      );

      console.log(`Successfully sent ${amount} tokens to ${address}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error sending tokens to ${address}:`, error);
    }
  }

  console.log('Airdrop complete');
}

// Start the airdrop
airdropTokens().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the network is currently quite congested, so it's not rare that transactions fail, especially if you're not adding priority fees like in your case. Check out [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/how-can-i-analyze-the-reason-for-frequent-blockheightexceeded-errors/9346#9346) to learn more about transaction failure and how to handle it.