# Help Needed: Token Transfer Script Entering Retry Loop on Solana

Tags: web3.js

I'm facing a challenge with a token transfer script on the Solana blockchain and need some guidance. My transactions fail to confirm, leading to repeated retries without a clear indication of the problem. In another version of the code I can print a tx but it never shows up on explorer.

**Here is my code**

```
    Connection,
    Keypair,
    PublicKey,
    Transaction,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    sendTransaction
} = require('@solana/web3.js');

const {
    getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
    createTransferInstruction,
} = require('@solana/spl-token');

const bs58 = require('bs58');
const {Wallet} = require("@project-serum/anchor");

// Setup Solana connection
const connection = new Connection('https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=REDACTED'); 

async function isBlockhashExpired(blockhash) {
    const {lastValidBlockHeight} = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const currentBlockHeight = await connection.getBlockHeight();
    return currentBlockHeight > lastValidBlockHeight;
}
async function checkTransactionConfirmation(txid, connection) {
    let hashExpired = false;
    let txSuccess = false;
    let maxRetries = 5;
    while (!hashExpired && !txSuccess && maxRetries-- > 0) {
        const { value: status } = await connection.getSignatureStatus(txid, {searchTransactionHistory: true});
        if (status && (status.confirmationStatus === 'confirmed' || status.confirmationStatus === 'finalized')) {
            txSuccess = true;
            console.log(`Transaction confirmed with txid: ${txid}`);
            return true; // Transaction confirmed
        } else {
            // Check if blockhash expired
            const blockhashResponse = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');
            hashExpired = await isBlockhashExpired(blockhashResponse.lastValidBlockHeight, connection);
            if (hashExpired) {
                console.log(`Blockhash has expired for txid: ${txid}`);
                break; // Exit loop if blockhash expired
            }
            // Wait before retrying
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Wait for 1 second
        }
    }
    if (!txSuccess) {
        console.error(`Transaction with txid ${txid} failed to confirm.`);
        return false; // Transaction failed or is unconfirmed
    }
}

async function sendToken(mintAddress, transferAmount, recipientPublicKey, senderKeypair) {

    try {
        // Get sender and receiver token accounts
        const senderTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            senderKeypair,
            mintAddress,
            senderKeypair.publicKey,
        );
        const recipientTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            senderKeypair,
            mintAddress,
            recipientPublicKey,
        );
        console.log('Sender token account:', senderTokenAccount.address.toString());
        console.log('Sender token account owner:', senderTokenAccount.owner.toString());
        console.log('Recipient public key:', recipientPublicKey.toString());
        console.log(transferAmount, 'tokens will be sent to the recipient token account:', recipientTokenAccount.address.toString());
        // Prepare transaction
        let transaction = new Transaction().add(
            createTransferInstruction(
                senderTokenAccount.address,
                recipientTokenAccount.address,
                senderKeypair.publicKey,
                transferAmount,
            ),
        );

        // Attempt to send the transaction with retries for blockhash expiration
        let signature = '';
        let maxRetries = 5;
        let retryCount = 0;
        let blockhashExpired = false;
        do {
            transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
            transaction.feePayer = senderKeypair.publicKey;
            try {
                signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [senderKeypair], {skipPreflight: false});
                console.log('Transfer successful, transaction signature:', signature);
                break; // Exit loop on success
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error sending token:', error);
                blockhashExpired = await isBlockhashExpired(transaction.recentBlockhash);
                if (!blockhashExpired) {
                    console.log(`Retrying transaction... Retry count: ${++retryCount}`);
                }
            }
        } while (retryCount < maxRetries && !blockhashExpired);

        if (blockhashExpired) {
            console.error('Transaction failed: Blockhash expired and max retries reached.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error preparing or sending token:', error);
    }
}

// Run the function to send the token
async function main() {
    const [mintAddress, transferAmount, recipientPublicKey, privateKey] = process.argv.slice(2);
    if (!mintAddress || !transferAmount || !recipientPublicKey || !privateKey) {
        console.error("Usage: node script.js <mintAddress> <transferAmount> <recipientPublicKey> <privateKey>");
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('Transfer Script Called with arguments; mintAddress:', mintAddress, 'transferAmount:', transferAmount, 'recipientPublicKey:', recipientPublicKey, 'privateKey:');
    try {
        const senderKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(privateKey));
        const recipient = new PublicKey(recipientPublicKey);
        const mint = new PublicKey(mintAddress);

        await sendToken(mint, transferAmount, recipient, senderKeypair);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in main:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

Sounds weird but this script was working previously I am sure. It stopped working recently.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the network is currently quite congested, so it's not rare that transactions fail, especially if you're not adding priority fees like in your case. Check out [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/how-can-i-analyze-the-reason-for-frequent-blockheightexceeded-errors/9346#9346) to learn more about transaction failure and how to handle it.

Comment: I added priority fees and problem solved thanks