# Bypass TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, send-transaction, error

So, i've been trying to send multiple addresses my token using Javascript (@solana/web3.js and @solana/spl-token).

Sadly, the same error occurs multiple times, TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError.
I understand why the error occurs and been trying different methods to solve this issue.
But still, is there a effective way to bypass this error?

> TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature
> 4iKv2StDaXggoicXmPkBREfp1ZcFz6RtyXn2J23YYF39kSJ9e7MPNCwpeoxL6X3jeKkRWxTdeWWz1L6EGT6xkLYA
> has expired: block height exceeded.
> at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy

The time it takes for one transaction to execute makes it more worth using my wallet and just manually make the transaction which is unsustainable since i have some wallets to send.

Comment: I think it would be useful for a good answer to see the code you work with.

The cookbook guidelines do not help here? https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions/retry#customizing-rebroadcast-logic
(with await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext() and setting it to transaction and sending)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/how-can-i-analyze-the-reason-for-frequent-blockheightexceeded-errors)