# hung transactions (connection.sendTransaction return txHash but it never mined)

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, transactions, rpc, validator

```
const signature: signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [account], options)
```

I am sending multiple transactions via private key
I get a hash of the transaction but it doesn't get into the network, I tried to use priority fee but it doesn't help.
No problem on devnet, but on mainnet it happens very often.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/how-can-i-analyze-the-reason-for-frequent-blockheightexceeded-errors)